# How can I see the IPs of the computers that queried my Azure OpenAI resource via the Azure OpenAI API?

Tags: azure, logging, ip

I created several Azure OpenAI resources in my Azure account. I deployed GPT models in each of the Azure OpenAI resources. I access them via the Azure OpenAI API.

How can I see the IPs of the computers that queried my Azure OpenAI resource via the Azure OpenAI API?